# Pow function in recursion C++

Tags: c++, recursion, pow

Can pow function be used in a recursive function?
For example:

```
double exponencial(double x, int n){
if(n>0)
return (pow(x,n)/n)+exponencial(x,n-1);
return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you think it can't be used?

Comment: You can use it. In this particular case, it is obviously a bad idea though. The name of the function is also a bad idea, since that isn't what you are computing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use any function in recursion. `pow` is simply a function nothing special about it.

Comment: Agreed, but maybe should note that there are a few functions that are not suitable for recursion - some of the time functions and for example `strtok`.

Comment: someone told me that I could't and I thought that was weird... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recursion does not put any limits on what functions you can and cannot use. So yes, `pow` can be used in a recursive function.

In your example, `pow(x,n)` will be called first (most likely), and the return value will be divided by n. Then, all relevant data is pushed onto the stack (including the answer of the computation we just did), and `exponencial(x,n-1)` is called. When this recursive call returns, the data is popped from the stack again, and our final result is calculated and returned.

Answer (score 0):

**YES.. You Can**

Its just a function that works similar to any other function you have written